# libevent multithread http server

Tags: c++, multithreading, libevent

i have such problem. I need to write multithread http server using libevent, but don't using `<evhttp.h>`. So i have problems with handle request. So i have

```
int main()
{
    ..............
    /*Some standard  stuff for binding to port*/
    ..............
    ev_accept = event_new(evbase_accept, listenfd, EV_READ|EV_PERSIST, on_accept, NULL);
    event_add(ev_accept, NULL);
    for(int i = 0;i < 4; i++) {
        std::thread (threadF).detach();
    }
    event_base_dispatch(evbase_accept);
```

So i try 2 possible variants: 
1) i'll try in `on_accept` for each connection create client_fd with `client_fd=accept(...)` and then add it to my `queue` for handling, and  then in threadF i pop element from queue and dispatch event for it, but i failed with too many fd open
2) in `on_accept` add `fd` to queue and then in `threadF` pop `fd` and `client_fd=accept(...)`, but this fails too, but this fails too.
So what another possibilities you can advise me. Or what is the best strategy for multithreading handle request? Thank you.

Comment: Do you ever close the `fd` handle?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious fd from bind to port-No, fd from accept-yes, after i write all info to client